# What factors could change the permission of a file?

Tags: python, file

I'm creating a directory using the `makedirs` function:

```
makedirs(self.output_dir, exist_ok=True)
```

I'm then copying some files from a temporary directory (`temp_dir`) inside this new directory.

In the end, and according to the Python documentation, I expect the permission of `output_dir` to be `rwxrwxrwx`.

> os.**makedirs**(path[, mode])
>
> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all
>   intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>   Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or
>   cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal).

However, the permission of `output_dir` turns out to be `rwx------`. I don't understand this result because I'm not doing any manipulation of the permission of `output_dir` anywhere in my code. I'm not using `os.chmod` for example.

Assuming I run my Python script as root, what factors could have changed the permission of the directory?

**EDIT**

I noticed that the temporary directory `temp_dir` has the same unexpected permission (`rwxrwxrwx`). I create it by using the following function:

```
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
```

Is this expected behavior? I couldn't find anything on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a umask present before running the python then the directory creation honours the umask.

E.g

```
umask -S u=rwx,g=,o=
```

Then

```
import os
os.makedirs(...
```

Comment: My umask is set to `022`, so I was wrong and I should expect `0755` as permission, not `0777`. However the permission I get in the end is not `0755` either. So I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: You need to post your whole program, or an equivalent whole test program, to get the best help.

Comment: Also your original question was “what factors” which is an open question. I gave you one of those factors. If you now edit your question to be more closed you should rephrase it better.  I.e why does my program do X which I didn’t expect?